# Hosting files on Amazon S3 and checking Username and password in request URL are valid

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I would like to know if the following is possible on Amazon S3 and have any guidance on how to achieve it.

We have a system that will generate many 1000's of static XML files, in a particular file structure, e.g.:

```
    \123\456\1.xml
    \123\456\2.xml
    \123\789\1.xml 
    \123\789\2.xml
    \456\222\1.xml
    etc...
```

We would like end users to be able to access these files directly from S3, using a URL something like:

```
    https://xml.mydomain.com/123/456/1.xml?UN=username&PW=password
    or
    https://xml.mydomain.com/456/222/1.xml?UN=username&PW=password
    or
    https://xml.mydomain.com/456/222/1.xml  (UN and PW embedded in header request)
```

The file should only be returned if the username and password passed in the URL are valid.  (Say validated against a list stored in another file on S3, or some other location).

This seems to me to be a simple scenario.  Is it possible?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: It is a "simple" scenario, but it isn't something that can be done by S3 alone, using built-in capabilities.  You'd need another component as "glue," to either generate the signed redirects discussed below, or to directly proxy authorized requests through to S3.

Answer (score 0):

You should first and foremost consult the [AWS documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/s3-access-control.html) about the topic. As long as AWS IAM accounts are involved, you can very fine-grained control the access to your objects.

What you're asking for sounds like a use case for [*presigned URLs*](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html). You can generate a URL containing a time-limited token allowing access to the object. At the moment you need to generate this URL programmatically using one of the SDKs or using Visual Studio; at the time of writing only Java and .NET are documented, but I know that in fact the Python SDK also contains this functionality, and therefore possibly others as well.

Note that a presigned token cannot be revoked, unlike a username and password. This is replaced by having the tokens expire, so you should choose a short validity window. The most practical implementation of this might be to have a server which does authentication in whatever custom way you need, then generates a presigned URL with a very short validity (a few minutes suffice) and redirects the authenticated user to that URL. This leaves you in full control over authentication while reaping the benefit of hosting files on S3.

Answer (score 0):

There can be more than one solution based on your requirement and how you would like to implement.

- Pre signed URL seems a good solution but, it won't allow you to pass username and password. For pre-signed URL using `aws-cli`, refer the following link:
  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/presign.html
- Another one: Integrate API gateway with lambda, where you can pass username and password as a body (POST) and lambda can return a pre-signed URL or the content of S3 object itself. There are also different strategies you could use to authenticate requests.

**Note:** Passing username and password as a URL parameter is a very bad idea.